# Save selected items in RecyclerView when switching Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an activity consisting of 3 fragment tabs that you can switch between. Each of these fragments have a RecyclerView where items are selected/highlighted when clicking. This is done with `holder.setSelected(true)` in `onBindViewHolder` in my custom RecyclerView Adapter.

The problem is when I switch between the three fragments, the selected items are removed when they are out of sight. I have tried saving the state of the RecyclerView in `onPause` and restoring it in `onResume`, but this didn't work.

How are the selected items saved and retrieved properly?

Here is my custom RecyclerView Adapter (The `interface OnItemClickListener` is not used in my current version):

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ExerciseViewHolder> {

private String[] mExampleList;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {

}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public static class ExerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView mTextView1;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    CardView mCardView;

    public ExerciseViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewExercise);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    void setSelected(boolean selected){
        mTextView1.setSelected(selected);
    }
}

public ExerciseAdapter(String[] exampleList) {
    mExampleList = exampleList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ExerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.exercise_item,parent,false);

    ExerciseViewHolder evh = new ExerciseViewHolder(v, mListener);

    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExerciseViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.mTextView1.setText(mExampleList[position]);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.setSelected(true);
            Day1Activity.setTimer();

        }
    });

    holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.setSelected(false);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.length;
}
```

This is one of the Fragments containing the RecyclerView:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ExerciseAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


private View rootView;

DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();

String[] exercises = dataModel.C_lifts();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);

   buildRecyclerView();

    return rootView;
}

private void buildRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mAdapter = new ExerciseAdapter(exercises);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

The Activity that handles the Fragments using a ViewPager:

```
public class Day1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private static TextView textViewTimer;

private static final String TAG = "Activity";

private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.day1_layout);

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerContainer);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    textViewTimer = findViewById(R.id.textViewTimer);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    int weekNumber = MainActivity.getWeekNumber();

    String frag1Title = "C-S";
    String frag2Title = "C-B";
    String frag3Title;
    if(weekNumber < 5) {
        frag3Title = "Rack Pulls";
    } else {
        frag3Title = "2ct Paused Deadlift";
    }

    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Frag1(),frag1Title);
    adapter.addFragment(new Frag2(),frag2Title);
    adapter.addFragment(new Frag3(),frag3Title);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public static void setTimer() {
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(240*1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textViewTimer.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textViewTimer.setText("Time is up!");
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save selected items to `SparseBooleanArray` where *key* is items *position* and *value* is *true* or *false* depending on selection.

You have to save this array somewhere to reuse it later, when `Fragment` is recreated. You can save it in `onSaveInstanceState()` when Fragment is being detached and when you come back to the `Fragment` just check if saved instance has that array that you stored and pass it to `RecyclerView` adapter to use it in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I have now looked at `SpareseBooleanArray` and have created an Array in my Adapter with a setter and getter, so that I can save it in my Fragment with:  `ExerciseAdapter.setItemStateArray((SparseBooleanArray) bundle.getParcelable("myBooleanArray"));`.

And retrieve with: `bundle.putParcelable("myBooleanArray", new SparseBooleanArrayParcelable(ExerciseAdapter.getmItemsStateArray()));`.

The problem is however, that the `onSaveInstanceState` is never called when switching between Fragments. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using ViewPager or Tabs? BTW. Check if your Fragments are recreated by logging something in onStop() and onDestroyView()

Comment: If they are not recreated each time, you can save your array in private field in your Fragment instead. One more suggestion: Save this array in SharedPreferences in onPause() method and then reuse it in onResume() method. This will make sure that you recreate selected items even when your app is killed in the background by the system.

Comment: I have logged it and can see that it only calls onStop() when I switch between the Fragments. I have now made a private array field as you suggested, and it works great. However, I still need to pass this array to my RecyclerView Adapter, but I don't know how to do that, since the item is selected in `onBindViewHolder` using `holder.setSelected(true)` and not a position.

Comment: Well, if onStop() is called, that mean onCreateView() will be called for sure when you comeback to this Fragment. In onCreateView() you can pass that array and use it in onBindViewHolder() like so: e.g. `holder.setSelected(array.get(position, false));`. *array* is an array that has saved boolean values, *position* is used from onBindViewHolder() parameters and we use *false* to indicate new rows that have not been added to the array will not be selected, therefore false is called if get method does not find a key in boolean array.

Comment: I appreciate your help Thomas, and I am new at Android programming so please forgive me for not understanding. But I handle the selection of the items in the adapter itself. How do I call this selection from my Fragment? I have no ViewHolder to pass on in order to do holder.setSelected(array.get(position, false));

Comment: I do not have a lot of time now. I might look at this problem more at the weekend. :)